How do I access a singleton dataController in an app intent?
I made an app that uses a singleton DataController which is passed around the SwiftUI views via EnvironmentObject. That singleton is responsible for handling the CoreData under the hood.
How can I access the dataController instance in the AppIntent? Thank you so much!
I've tried the following code:
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI

struct AddSentence: AppIntent {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Add new sentence"
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        dataController.newSentence()
        
        return .result()
    }
}

But I get a Fatal error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type DataController found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for DataController may be missing as an ancestor of this view.


SwiftUI property wrappers only work in views,

I believe @EnvironmentObject works only with SwiftUI View.

You can pass it normally

struct AddSentence: AppIntent {
    var dataController = DataController.shared // Use the singleton instance
        
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Add new sentence"
        
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        dataController.newSentence()
    
        return .result()
    }
}


Because DataController is a singleton, you can not even pass it, but initiate it in AddSentence without passing

